# Converting a Java enumeration to a Scala Map

Tags: scala

Is there a way to take a java based API that loops over property names and someone add the key/value pairs to a Scala Map[String, Object] ?

```
Enumeration properties = something.getPropertyNames();
while (properties.hasMoreElements())
{
    String propName = (String) srcProperties.nextElement();
    Object v = something.getValue(propName);
}
```

Comment: what is the Object in this case?

Comment: I guess in would be considered Any in scala.  It is "anything" untyped for now.

Comment: An Enumeration is a sequence, how do you want a Map from that?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing a Java `Enumeration` with the `Properties` object it was obtained from. Like in
 `Enumeration propertyNames = props.getPropertyNames()`

We cannot create a map from the resulting Enumeration, because it's only a sequence of Strings, but we can obtain a `Map[String,String]` from the original `Properties` object.

```
 import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
 val propertyMap = props.asScala  // mutable map
 // or
 val propertyMap = props.asScala.toMap  // immutable map
```

Comment: @coolbreeze has this answered your question? Consider accepting it.